# How to add tooltip on Angular nvd3 line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I'm using the following charts: https://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.with.focus.chart.html

I want to be able to hover on the chart points and see the x/y axis values for that point. I noticed that I can add tooptip to the chart. I tried with the following but nothing shows when I hover on one of the points on the graph.

```
$scope.toolTipContentFunction = function(){
      return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
        return  'Super New Tooltip' +
          '<h1>' + key + '</h1>' +
          '<p>' +  y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
      }
    };

<div ng-init="dashboardType = 'Bing'">
      <nvd3-line-with-focus-chart
        data="data"
        id="dashboardChart"
        height="400"
        height2="50"
        margin="{left:80,top:50,bottom:30,right:50}"
        yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        x2AxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        tooltips="true"
        tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()">
        <svg></svg>
      </nvd3-line-with-focus-chart>
    </div>
```

Is that the write function to use in order to do what I want? If yes - am I missing something? I've also tried hitting a break point inside my `toolTipContentFunction` function  by hovering my mouse on the chart, but it's not stopping. Not sure what this tooltip supposed to do.

I'm using Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I should've set the interactive mode to be true.

```
<nvd3-line-with-focus-chart
        data="data"
        id="dashboardChart"
        height="400"
        height2="50"
        margin="{left:80,top:50,bottom:30,right:50}"
        yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        x2AxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        tooltips="true"
        interactive="true"
        tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()">
        <svg></svg>
      </nvd3-line-with-focus-chart>
```